# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str . while working with json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, django, django-views

I am making a simple weather app using API. **I got the error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**. I know where the problem is but I don't know how to solve it. my code is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import urllib.request
import json
```

## Create your views here.

```
def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        city = request.POST['city']

        source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city+'&appid=5ba7df1f751428007642bf4e5f6c4c9a').read()
    list_of_data = json.loads(source)

        data = {
            "country_code": str(list_of_data['sys']['country']),
            "coordinate" : str(list_of_data['coord']['lon']) + ' '
            + str(list_of_data['coord']['lat']),
            "temp" : str(list_of_data['main']['temp']) + 'k',
            "pressure": str(list_of_data['main']['pressure']),
            "humidity": str(list_of_data['main']['humidity']),
            "weather" : str(list_of_data['weather']['description']),
        }
        print(data)
    else: 
        data = {}

    return render(request, 'main/index.html', data)`
```

The problem is in the last line of the **data dictionary**. I don't know how to write it. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list_of_data['weather'][0]['description']` instead.

Weather contains a list structure (note the use of square brackets inside the weather section of the JSON) where there is the option for more than one item. In most cases you will just want the first one so use `[0]`

Comment: It Worked. Thanks. Can you tell the reason why it worked? it will be really helpful.

Comment: @SaifKhan I edited the question to explain why.

Answer (score 0):

```
context = {
        "data": data
    }

return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)
```

This should work